# System.Net.Mail Server Response was 5.7.1

Tags: c#, .net, system.net.mail

I am building a windows forms application for a school that has a very tight network (meaning the person I am building it for has to ask their IT services to do everything).

This application sends emails out and I am using System.Net.Mail library to do so.

```
        SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("SMTPAddress");

        MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage("admin@xyz.com", emailAddressTo);

        mailObj.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailObj.Subject = "Subject";
        mailObj.Body = "<h2>Test E-Mail Message from the TSENS</h2>";

        SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SMTPUserName, SMTPPassword);
        SMTPServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;  //This is new code

        SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
```

I'm wondering if this line: `SMTPServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;` will solve the latest error message he got when trying to send out an e-mail:

[image: Error 5.7.1]

Is there something else that I am missing?

Just in case you are wondering the SMTPUserName and Password is his e-mail username and password that he uses to send and receive mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that the SMTPUsername his mailadress isn't "admin@xyz.com" which is used as the sender of the mailmessage.

The mailserver seems to validate if the person doing the send is allowed to send mails on behalf of admin@xyz.com which appearantly isn't the case.

According to the SMTP specs error 5.7.1 stands for "Unable to relay" which is what you try to do.

Comment: so I should change admin@xyz.com to his e-mail address?

Comment: Yes  ---(extra text needed to be able to add a commment:))

Comment: ok - I'm going to give this a go (I made the change).  Now he just needs to install it and run it.  Your answer makes sense.  Hopefully it will work.  I'll mark it as answered as soon as I get a successful email send.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
        emailClient = new SmtpClient(yourEMAILSERVER);
        emailClient.Send(yourMailMessageObject); // in your case "mailObj" that you have defined already
```

I would avoid using SMTPServer class or set its Credentials or DeliveryMethod properties.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the items I was missing in my OP

Comment: Got it. I guess it should work if the FROM username in MailMessage object is set to an existing one.